# JMeter - Throughput Shaping Timer does not keep the requests/sec rate

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Ultimate Thread Group and fixed 1020 threads count for entire test duration - 520 seconds.
I've made a throughput diagram as follows:

[image]

The load increses over 10 seconds so the spikes shouldn't be very steep. Since the max RPS is 405 and max response time is around 25000ms 1020 threads should be enough.

However, when I run the test (`jmeter -t spikes-nomiss.jmx  -l spikes-nomiss.csv -e -o spikes-nomiss -n`) I have the following graph for hits/seconds.

The threads are stopped for few seconds and suddenly 'wake up'. I can't find a reason for it. The final minute has a lot higher frequency of the calls. I've set heap size to 2GBs and resources are available, the CPU usage does not extend 50% during peaks, and memory is around 80% (4Gbs of ram on the machine). Seeking any help to fix the freezes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to monitor JMeter's JVM using [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) as it might be the case JMeter is not capable of create spikes due to insufficient resources. The slowdowns can be caused by excessive [Garbage Collection](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)
2. It might be the case 1020 threads are not enough to reach the desired throughput as it depends mainly on your application response time. If your application response time is higher than 300 milliseconds - you will not be able to get 405 RPS using 1020 threads. It might be a better idea to consider using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-4-stepping-thread-group-and-concurrency-thread/) which can be connected to the Throughput Shaping Timer via [Schedule Feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function)

Comment: Concurrency Thread Group doesn't solve my issue. I've set the feedback function max threads to 4000 and the tests now do not even reach target throughput. I ran the JConsole and there is no sign of abnormal garbage collection - there are 16 calls at the first seconds of the test but later only 4. Heap memory never reaches even quarter of the available space, CPU never goes above 15%. Is it possible that JMeter cannot setup this number of threads in such a short time? In feedback function I've set (timer, 100,4000,1000) so maybe 1000 threads in backup is too little?

Comment: Here is the graph from JConsole: [link](https://i.imgur.com/odFsnwf.png) and here is the test graph [link](https://i.imgur.com/oyvFeTg.png). From 16:06:11 to ~16:16:40 there is a freeze. But the GC was not doing anything during that time.  I performed this on Dummy Samplers just to be sure it's not related to response times so the pause must be coming from some other source, which I am yet to discover.

Comment: I've run the test on DEBUG mode and there are no logs during the freeze, do you have any other idea why does it happen?